# Can anyone advise a starting point for the effect that causes graphics to 'shimmy' into place onload

Tags: javascript, html, css

...such as that used for http://vasonanetworks.com?

Not only when you enter the site but as you scroll, there's a sluggish nature to the graphics and I wonder if anyone has any insight into how this accomplished.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, check out jQuery and the animation functions.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Specifically for working with the scroll event: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Thanks @TimBolton, I checked that out and I'm familiar with jQuery animations, such as slideToggle and animate etc but just not sure how to cause it to happen 'on scroll' or delayed like that.